# Using multiple namespaces inside xml

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have an xml which contains two namespaces. I need one to be changed as ns0 and the other as ns1.
The namespace http://www.nrf-arts.org/IXRetail/namespace/ needs to be added as ns0 and http://www.datavantagecorp.com/xstore/ as ns1. Basiscally the second namespace is a reference namespace.

I have tried the below code. But it did not help me.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://sample.com/s" 
xmlns:ns0="http://www.nrf-arts.org/IXRetail/namespace/" xmlns:ns1="http://www.datavantagecorp.com/xstore/" 
xmlns:dtv="http://www.datavantagecorp.com/xstore/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/">

<xsl:copy>

<xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>

</xsl:copy>

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="node()[not(self::dtv)]">

<xsl:element name="ns0:{local-name()}">

<xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>

</xsl:element>

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="dtv:*">

<xsl:element name="ns1:{local-name()}">

<xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>

</xsl:element>

</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The structure I have

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Sales_Posting>
   <row>
      <POSLog xmlns="http://www.nrf-arts.org/IXRetail/namespace/"
              xmlns:dtv="http://www.datavantagecorp.com/xstore/"
              xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xs:schemaLocation="http://www.nrf-arts.org/IXRetail/namespace/ POSLog.xsd">
         <Transaction CancelFlag="true"
                      OfflineFlag="false"
                      TrainingModeFlag="false"
                      dtv:AppVersion="17.0.0.0.716 - 0.0.0 - 0.0"
                      dtv:TransactionType="RETAIL_SALE">
            <dtv:OrganizationID>1</dtv:OrganizationID>
            <RetailStoreID>103</RetailStoreID>
            <WorkstationID>3</WorkstationID>
            <TillID>47957</TillID>
            <SequenceNumber>1396</SequenceNumber>
            <BusinessDayDate>2019-05-08</BusinessDayDate>
            <BeginDateTime>2019-05-08T14:51:48.731</BeginDateTime>
            <EndDateTime>2019-05-23T23:37:41.209</EndDateTime>
            <OperatorID>47957</OperatorID>
            <CurrencyCode>INR</CurrencyCode>
            <RollOverCode>0</RollOverCode>
            <MMSTxnType>87</MMSTxnType>
```

Expected output:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns0:Sales_Posting xmlns:ns0="http://www.nrf-arts.org/IXRetail/namespace/">
   <ns0:row>
      <ns0:POSLog>
         <ns0:Transaction CancelFlag="false" TrainingModeFlag="false" OfflineFlag="" ns1:TransactionType="" ns1:AppVersion="17.0.0.0.716 - 0.0.0 - 0.0" ns1:crossChannelReturn="" ns1:InventoryDocumentSubType="" ns1:InventoryDocumentType="" xmlns:ns1="http://www.datavantagecorp.com/xstore/">
            <ns1:OrganizationID xmlns:ns1="http://www.datavantagecorp.com/xstore/">1</ns1:OrganizationID>
            <ns0:RetailStoreID>103</ns0:RetailStoreID>
            <ns0:WorkstationID>3</ns0:WorkstationID>
            <ns0:TillID>47957</ns0:TillID>
            <ns1:CashDrawerID xmlns:ns1="http://www.datavantagecorp.com/xstore/"/>
            <ns0:SequenceNumber/>
            <ns0:BusinessDayDate/>
            <ns0:BeginDateTime/>
            <ns0:EndDateTime/>
            <ns0:OperatorID/>
            <ns0:CurrencyCode/>
            <ns1:FiscalNumber xmlns:ns1="http://www.datavantagecorp.com/xstore/"/>
            <ns1:DeviceId xmlns:ns1="http://www.datavantagecorp.com/xstore/"/>
            <ns1:FiscalSessionNumber xmlns:ns1="http://www.datavantagecorp.com/xstore/"/>
            <ns1:PosTransactionProperties xmlns:ns1="http://www.datavantagecorp.com/xstore/"/>
            <ns0:RollOverCode/>
            <ns0:MMSTxnType/>
            <ns0:SuspendReasonCode/>
            <ns0:MMSReasonType/>
            <ns0:MEPNumber/>
            <ns0:TransactionComment/>
            <ns0:TransNumberReturnWOReceipt/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the fact that the namespace prefix is arbitrary, and any XML parser shouldn't care what they are (as long as the actual namespace is as expected), the below should help you:

**Stylesheet**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:ns0="http://www.nrf-arts.org/IXRetail/namespace/"
    xmlns:ns1="http://www.datavantagecorp.com/xstore/"
    xmlns:dtv="http://www.datavantagecorp.com/xstore/">

    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="@*">
        <xsl:copy-of select="." />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="dtv:*">
        <xsl:element name="ns1:{local-name(.)}">
            <xsl:value-of select="text()" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node()[local-name() != '']">
        <xsl:element name="ns0:{local-name()}">
            <xsl:value-of select="text()" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Three templates:

- Match any attributes and just copy them across.
- Match anything in the `dtv` namespace, rename the prefix to `ns1` and copy the text content and recursively map any children
- Match any other nodes and apply the `http://www.nrf-arts.org/IXRetail/namespace/` namespace with `ns0` prefix, copy the text content and recursively map any children

I think your input was truncated in the question, but it seemed to do the trick.

**Input**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Sales_Posting>
    <row>
        <POSLog xmlns="http://www.nrf-arts.org/IXRetail/namespace/"
            xmlns:dtv="http://www.datavantagecorp.com/xstore/"
            xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xs:schemaLocation="http://www.nrf-arts.org/IXRetail/namespace/ POSLog.xsd">
            <Transaction CancelFlag="true" OfflineFlag="false"
                TrainingModeFlag="false" dtv:AppVersion="17.0.0.0.716 - 0.0.0 - 0.0"
                dtv:TransactionType="RETAIL_SALE">
                <dtv:OrganizationID>1</dtv:OrganizationID>
                <RetailStoreID>103</RetailStoreID>
                <WorkstationID>3</WorkstationID>
                <TillID>47957</TillID>
                <SequenceNumber>1396</SequenceNumber>
                <BusinessDayDate>2019-05-08</BusinessDayDate>
                <BeginDateTime>2019-05-08T14:51:48.731</BeginDateTime>
                <EndDateTime>2019-05-23T23:37:41.209</EndDateTime>
                <OperatorID>47957</OperatorID>
                <CurrencyCode>INR</CurrencyCode>
                <RollOverCode>0</RollOverCode>
                <MMSTxnType>87</MMSTxnType>
            </Transaction>
        </POSLog>
    </row>
</Sales_Posting>
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns0:Sales_Posting
    xmlns:ns0="http://www.nrf-arts.org/IXRetail/namespace/">
    <ns0:row>
        <ns0:POSLog
            xs:schemaLocation="http://www.nrf-arts.org/IXRetail/namespace/ POSLog.xsd"
            xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <ns0:Transaction CancelFlag="true"
                OfflineFlag="false" TrainingModeFlag="false"
                dtv:AppVersion="17.0.0.0.716 - 0.0.0 - 0.0"
                xmlns:dtv="http://www.datavantagecorp.com/xstore/"
                dtv:TransactionType="RETAIL_SALE">
                <ns1:OrganizationID
                    xmlns:ns1="http://www.datavantagecorp.com/xstore/">1</ns1:OrganizationID>
                <ns0:RetailStoreID>103</ns0:RetailStoreID>
                <ns0:WorkstationID>3</ns0:WorkstationID>
                <ns0:TillID>47957</ns0:TillID>
                <ns0:SequenceNumber>1396</ns0:SequenceNumber>
                <ns0:BusinessDayDate>2019-05-08</ns0:BusinessDayDate>
                <ns0:BeginDateTime>2019-05-08T14:51:48.731</ns0:BeginDateTime>
                <ns0:EndDateTime>2019-05-23T23:37:41.209</ns0:EndDateTime>
                <ns0:OperatorID>47957</ns0:OperatorID>
                <ns0:CurrencyCode>INR</ns0:CurrencyCode>
                <ns0:RollOverCode>0</ns0:RollOverCode>
                <ns0:MMSTxnType>87</ns0:MMSTxnType>
            </ns0:Transaction>
        </ns0:POSLog>
    </ns0:row>
</ns0:Sales_Posting>
```

Comment: I am getting error ** Error: Invalid element name. QName cannot end with colon: {ns0:} ** while trying to transform as per the xsl shared by you. It's not working. I used online tool https://xslttest.appspot.com/ to test. Thanks for your reply. Kindly help me.

Comment: Hi @Siji - that error was due to matching the root node which is "nameless" (local-name() = '') - I have added a quick fix which should solve that. I was running the transform through eclipse and hadn't noticed that error which wasn't preventing the overall execution of the transform.